# Como esses métodos Setters não estão sendo utilizados?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, getters-setters

Estou criando um app Java/Android onde o seu trabalho é basicamente exibir uma lista para o usuário sobre quais itens ainda temos disponíveis em estoque.

Para fazer essa lista utilizei um **Recycler View**, os dados (itens do estoque) são adicionados manualmente por mim no **Firebase**, este por sua vez espelha os dados como uma lista (recyclerView) no meu app.

Até ai tudo ocorreu muito bem...

Porém, ao executar o app aparece a seguinte mensagem no meu Logcat:

`W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for dT (difiteria e tétano) found on class com.imagine.edielsonpereira.cs_ivacinasstock.activity.modelagem.Vacina`

Percebi também que os meus métodos **Setters**, na minha classe de modelagem, não estão sendo utilizados pois os mesmos estão esmaecidos, presumo que o problema esteja aí.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue o aviso (não diria que é um erro) no Logcat:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Configuração do **Realtime Database** que faz comunicação com o meu app:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue a configuração da classe principal:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Classe ConfiguracaoFirebase**

```
package com.imagine.edielsonpereira.cs_ivacinasstock.activity.config;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class ConfiguracaoFirebase {

    private static DatabaseReference firebase;

    //Retorna Instancia do Firebase
    public static DatabaseReference getFirebaseDatabase(){
        if(firebase == null){
            firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        }
        return firebase;
    }

}
```

**Adapter:**

```
package com.imagine.edielsonpereira.cs_ivacinasstock.activity.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.support.annotation.ColorInt;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.imagine.edielsonpereira.cs_ivacinasstock.R;
import com.imagine.edielsonpereira.cs_ivacinasstock.activity.modelagem.Vacina;

import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Vacina> listaVacinas;
    Context context;

    public Adapter(List<Vacina> listaVacinas, Context context) {
        this.listaVacinas = listaVacinas;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        //Converte o objeto do tipo XML em uma View.
        View itemLista = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_lista, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemLista);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

        Vacina vacina = listaVacinas.get(i);
        myViewHolder.vacina.setText(vacina.getTipoVacina());
        myViewHolder.doses.setText(vacina.getDoses());

         //Muda cor do texto das vacinas com saldo 0 para vermelho
       if(vacina.getDoses() == "0 doses" ){
            myViewHolder.doses.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaVacinas.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imagem;
        TextView vacina;
        TextView doses;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imagem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageSeringa);
            vacina = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textVacina);
            doses = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDoses);

        }
    }

}
```

Desde já agradeço a disponibilidade em me ajudar...

Comment: setTipoVacina... setDoses... estão esmaecidos, ainda não entendi o porquê.

Comment: Isso acontece porque você não utiliza esses métodos. Já o log indica que , provavelmente, os nomes das propriedades no `Firebase` são diferentes dos nome dos `setters` e `getters`

Comment: Essa é a questão Ivan, como não estão sendo utilizados? Estes foram gerados automaticamente pelo Android Studio para tal função.

Comment: Você precisa chamá-los: `vacina.getVacina() e vacina.getDose()`. Mas isso não é um erro.

Comment: Segue sem funcionar aqui, o **RecyclerView** não espelha os meus dados que adicionei no **Firebase**.

Comment: Edite a pergunta adicionando  o código do `adapter`, da `activity` e do `Firebase Database` (não esqueça de rasurar alguma informação sensível). Só com essas informações da pergunta não será possível resolver seu problema.

Comment: Feito @IvanSilva, espero que tenha ficado um pouco mais claro.

Answer (score 0):

Então vamos lá Edielson!

> Primeiro vamos deixar claro: o fato dos métodos estarem esmanhecidos
>   só indica que não estão sendo utilizados. Não é um erro. Feito isso,
>   vamos ao problema real.

**O problema**

O seu problema é que quando você cria um `nó` no `Real Time Database` ele precisa ser uma espécie de cópia do seu modelo (classe). Dessa forma, ao atualizar ou recuperar esses dados, programaticamente, com o `SDK` do `Firebase`, ele mapeará todas as propriedades do `nó` com base nos nomes dos campos da classe que você passa como parâmetro para o `getValue()` lá no `onDataChange`.

O ponto importante é a forma como os dados ficarão armazenados no `database`. Isso é algo relativo ao projeto e depende de como esses dados serão recuperados de modo mais fácil. Mas observando que você precisa apenas de uma listas simples de vacinas, nós podemos modificar sua atual estrutura para algo assim

```
cs-i-vacinas-stock
      vacinas
         key_vacina_1
             nome
             tipo
             doses
         key_vacina_2
             nome
             tipo
             doses
             .
             .
             .
        key_vacina_N
            nome
            tipo
            doses
```

As `keys` devem ser definidas obrigatoriamente nessa estrutura. Elas irão diferenciar cada `nó` da lista (`árvore`). E isso pode ser feito automaticamente pelo `SDK` quando você salva dados pelo `app`, programaticamente. Ou deve ser feito manualmente, caso você insira os dados diretamente no console.

**Solução**

Para resolvermos seu problema utilizando as dicas que foram dadas, precisaremos modificar seu código. Então siga esses passos para implementarmos a solução.

1 - Modifique sua classe `Vacina.java` removendo o código de chamada ao `Firebase`. A única finalidade da classe é modelar seus dados e não fazer chamadas ao `database`.

```
public class Vacina {
   private String nome;
   private String tipo;
   private int doses;

   public Vacina() {
       // Esse construtor vazio é requerido pelo Firebase
   }

   public String getNome() {
      return nome;
   }

   public void setNome(String nome) {
      this.nome = nome;
   }

   public String getTipo() {
      return tipo;
   }

   public void setTipo(String tipo) {
      this.tipo = tipo;
   }

   public int getDoses() {
      return doses;
   }

   public void setDoses(int doses) {
      this.doses = doses;
   }
}
```

2 - Se as vacinas forem salvas programaticamente, o `Firebase` gerará `keys` de forma automática só precisando você chamar `push()`

```
Vacina vacina = new Vacina();
       vacina.setName("Tríplice Viral");
       vacina.setTipo("B");
       vacina.setDoses(1);

vacinasRef.child("vacinas")
       .push()   // Isso gerará uma nova key
       .setValue(vacina);
```

3 - Caso você queira inserir os dados manualmente, sempre gere uma `key` para cada nova vacina inserida na lista (use esse [site](https://randomkeygen.com/) na parte **CodeIgniter Encryption Keys**), ficando mais ou menos assim

```
cs-i-vacinas-stock
      vacinas
         dSYaFIUqY5oGw34gcwdiOHQIYmreyfws
                   nome: "Tríplice Viral"
                   tipo: "B"
                   doses: 1
         gbJw8JwhLhwMq7hBTHZn2fStsEhTFxfp
                   nome: "Tetraviral"
                   tipo: "A"
                   doses: 1
```

5 - Repare que o nome das propriedades do `nó` são as mesmas dos campos do seu modelo (nome, tipo e doses). Qualquer outra propriedade que não exista no seu modelo, será alertado no log que não foi encontrado nenhum campo correspondente. Mas isso pode ser facilmente resolvido criando o campo e seus `getters` e `setter` no modelo.

Acredito que você deva dar mais uma olhadinha na [documentção](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) do `Firebase` pra se familiarizar com o conceito da coisa.

Espero que tenha sido claro e que isso possa te ajudar. E qualquer coisa é só perguntar. Abraço!

Comment: Olá @IvanSilva, fiz as modificações que você me mostrou, retirei a chamada ao **Firebase** da minha classe Vacina.java, modifique a estrutura do **Realtime Database** adicionando chaves diferentes para cada produto (vacina) manualmente - quero trabalhar com no máximo 13 vacinas, então é fácil adicioná-las - e por fim verifiquei que os nomes das propriedades da classe são os mesmos da minha estrutura no Firebase. **Resultado:** O aviso no log consiste, os sets continuam esmaecidos e o meu app não lista os itens (vacinas). Se precisar visualizar as modificações, posso adicioná-las na pergunta.

Comment: Desculpe a demora, estou trabalhando muito ultimamente. Salientando mais uma vez que os métodos estarem **esmaecidos não configura um erro**. Se os logs persistem, você não utilizou a mesma estrutura que propus. Se for possível, faça uma segunda edição na pergunta (mantendo as informações atuais) com sua classe e os logs.

Comment: Então @IvanSilva tudo certo por aqui parceiro, quero deixar aqui o meu agradecimento à comunidade e principalmente a você, através da sua resposta modifiquei a minha estrutura **JSON** com os mesmos nomes dos atributos da minha classe **Vacina.java** e a coisa começou a fluir. Realmente os métodos **Setters** não era o problema, como prova disso, eles continuam esmaecidos com a aplicação funcionando normalmente (risos). O real problema do meu app era que a minha classe **ConfiguracaoFirebase.java** já estava capturando a instância do **Firebase** e eu nem me dava conta disso  **CONTINUA >>>**

Comment: Então depois de dar umas torradas nos neurônios aqui, consegui identificar este problema. Retirei a chamada `vacinasRef.child("VACINAS")` da minha classe principal e coloquei a referência **"VACINAS"** espelho da que está na estrutura do Firebase, como _path_ do `getReference` lá na minha classe **ConfiguracaoFirebase.java**. Ficou assim: `firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("VACINAS");` feito essas pequenas modificações a aplicação resolveu funcionar listando instantaneamente no meu **RecyclerView** todas as vacinas e quantidades destas que adiciono no **Firebase**. Show!